# Проблема с переменной

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

```
echo "name = nearest.properties.get('name');$('#metro').find($(\"[data-adrstations = name]\")).append('<a href=\"{$adr_guid}\">{$adr_post_title}</a>');";
```

Так почему-то не работает, а если вставить одно из значений вместо name, то работает, напрмер:

```
$('#metro').find($(\"[data-adrstations = 'метро Южная ']\")).append('<a href=\"{$adr_guid}\">{$adr_post_title}</a>');";
```

Блок который ищет выглядит так:

```
<div id="metro_flat_adress31" class="metro_flat_adress" style="position:absolute;top:634;left:298;" data-adrstations="метро Южная "></div>
```

Comment: name = nearest.properties.get('name');  
У вас эта переменная, часом, не пустая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

```
echo "name = nearest.properties.get('name');$('#metro').find($(\"[data-adrstations = '\"+name+\"']\")).append('<a href=\"{$adr_guid}\">{$adr_post_title}</a>');";
```

Comment: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-adrstations = метро Южная]

Comment: Поправил ответ, тоже запутался в кавычках.

Comment: Будет искать +name+

Comment: Почему вы так решили? http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/P6ajA/

Comment: Да, вы правы. У меня была пропущенна "

Answer (score -1):

data-adrstations = name. name здесь часом не переменная? Если да, то вам не кажется, что метод find считает ее в выражении просто за часть строки, тоесть [data-adrstations = name], а не [data-adrstations = 'метро Южная']. Оберните переменную в одинарные ковычки